# MS SQL Read value with apostrophe from table and save it in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am reading a value from table with apostrophe with which I create a dynamic query and than I run a sp to save it in another table, which works fine without apostrophe but throw an error when it contains an apostrophe.

Select @arguments = argument from Mytable

e.g.
set @sql = 'exec nameOfSP' + @arguments

@arguments value comes from database

@argument sample value '612f0', 'This is an example second string'

Yes I know and agree that this is very bad code smell and therefore the question is not about design (which unfortunately couldn't be changed) but about the best possible solution in current scenario.

I am looking possible for a solution with encoding?

Comment: please be more specific and show the query you have used

Comment: I'm sure we can help, show us your code.

Comment: Sounds like you are generating your dynamic sql with string concatenation, instead of using proper parameters.  Please avoid using string concatentation, because this opens up a big security hole.

Comment: OK, now you edited it. **Man, your application has a BIG security hole!!** Please use proper parameter passing.

Comment: Thanks all added an example above

Comment: not enough; can you show a sample value for `@arguments`?

Comment: I think this code is getting the procedure dynamically from a table. This has a very bad code smell to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a possibility of a quote coming through in your arguments do something like this:

```
set @sql = 'exec nameOfSP ' + REPLACE(@arguments, '''', '''''');
```

Comment: Thanks - this is one solution that I have thought of but was hoping there could be better solution than replacing / double quoting

Comment: The better solution is to redesign. Painful and expensive in the present, will save you a lot of time, pain and money in the long run

Comment: The OP has stated that redesign is not an option. Sometimes we just have to work with what we've got!

Comment: @johns I agree, but the op also stated they want a better solution. Redesign *is* the better solution... if it's too expensive then the op must go with the not so good solution... It's like asking to buy a ferrary when you only have the money for a ford focus... you want a better car, pay it's price!

Answer (score 0):

*"the question is not about design (which unfortunately couldn't be changed)"* seems like someone is going for the risk of saving in design that will cost a lot after... if you really must use dynamic sql like this you can use replace on ' to '' (that's right, just double it).
**However**, I must say that this is not a solution to your problem in any way, it's only a workaround.
You should do whatever you can to change the desing.

Comment: Thanks - this is a legacy system and not new, therefore actually we are the one paying for this design :-( . The cost is already too high to redesign this.